# Set up a forwarding mailbox in qmail?

Tags: email, mailbox, mail-forwarding

setting up a simple mailserver to forward all messages sent to one address to gmail.

So far I have a file
**/var/qmail/mailnames/myserver.com/username/.qmail** with a single line:

**&recepient@gmail.com**

I also have file **/var/qmail/users/assign** with:

**=username:localuser:2525:48:/var/qmail/mailnames/servername.com/username:::**

test email bounces with error "Sorry, no mailbox here by that name."

Thanks!

Comment: People still use qmail? I had to use it once, seemed very awkward to use. I'd suggest postfix or exim.

Comment: I ended up using postfix, it was pretty easy to get going after I found location of the log file

Answer (score 1):

Did you run [qmail-newu](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/infosys/mail/qmail/qmail-manual-html/man5/qmail-users.html)? Did you include the "." as the last line of the file? Is /var/qmail/mailnames/myserver.com/username/ owned by localuser?

It might be simpler for you to just use the alias directory.  Messages that don't match a user on the system get passed to the alias user (/var/qmail/alias) where they are handled as if the message were addressed to alias-localpart. In your case I think you would create this file:

```
/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-username
```

And that file would contain your forwarding instructions:

```
&recipient@gmail.com
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about newu tried all that. still no luck

Comment: You may need to restart qmail-send after creating the cdb file in /var/qmail/users/.  I know you can replace a file while it's running, but if you create the file new while it's running you might have to restart.

Comment: You don't need to restart when a cdb file is changed.  Qmail reads it on the next pass.

Comment: How would I create an alias for joining a Mailman mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you do that it will only do one domain whichever is default in /var/qmail/control, if you have multiple domains you should use vpopmail and on top I suggest you install QmailAdmin it'll help you with your forwarding among other useful things and it will be easier for you to manage through web gui.

Answer (score 1):

Can't adda comment (not enough reputation) but just want to confirm your paths -- I'm suspecting you've just swapped out the real-server name, but a sanity check is always a good thing :-)

Your users/assign file has a path of: `/var/qmail/mailnames/servername.com/username`

Whilst you say the .qmail file lives in: `/var/qmail/mailnames/myserver.com/username`

i.e., myserver.com vs. servername.com.

The other thing to check is that the target directory and .qmail file are chown'd by uid:gid 2525:48 as configured in the assign file, and that the file is chmod'd 644.

qmail will generally setuid() to the target user's account. When you've configured users up in the users/assign file, qmail will setuid to the uid specified in there. So if perms aren't right, the user won't exist.